# How to retrieve an image from Firebase Storage, with Firebase UID as a part of the image URL?

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

How do I retrieve an image from Firebase Storage, with Firebase UID as a part of the URL. I'm pretty new to Firebase, so I have most likely just made a mistake.

HTML:

```
   <div>
      <img id="profile-picture">
   </div>
```

JavaScript:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {

var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser;

var pfpurl = firebase.storage().ref("profile_pictures/" + uid);

document.querySelector('#profile-picture').src = pfpurl;

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unlikely that `document.querySelector('#profile-picture')` can download the image data directly from the `StorageReference` that you pass in, as that would require it to call the Firebase SDK.

If you want to download the image data over HTTPS, you need to first get the download URL for the image, as shown in the documentation on [downloading data from a URL](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files#download_data_via_url):

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {

  var uid = firebase.auth().currentUser;

  var ref = firebase.storage().ref("profile_pictures/" + uid);

  ref.getDownloadURL().then(function(url) {
    document.querySelector('#profile-picture').src = url;
  });
})
```

Comment: I got one step closer. But now I get an error: Firebase Storage: Object 'profile_pictures/[object Object]' does not exist.